# How to import and run a project of .class file in Eclipse or IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am trying to import a project https://github.com/mmoraless/DET-ABE that contains .class files instead of .java files for the source in Eclipse by importing existing projects into workspace option in but it does not get recognized as a project. I also tried to copy the folders that contain .class files into a new project but still does not work. When I tried to import with IntelliJ it was successful to import the project but when I tried to build the module all of the packages that contain .class files are not found although it is already there. Is there something wrong with how I handle the project?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me that the author simply dumped the compiled class files into the github repo ("Add files via upload" as commit message), without accessible source you cannot do too much about that apart from using it as is (the .class files, when you find the `main` function; but without docu that will be hard to do).

[JD-Gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) to the rescue! Download the project, decompile the class files with JD-Gui (or other Java decompiler, preferred by you), export the decompiled sources and *those* you can now export into an IDE as a project.

**Note:** After decompilation you have to take care not to distribute the code, as the current license does not allow that. It's a simple copyright by the author, and unline MIT/BSD/etc. this one legally does not allow you do distribute any derived work without the "OK" from the copyright holder.